# numpy turning matrixes into vectors and combining them

Tags: numpy

I have two matricies

```py
a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
b=[[5,6],[7,8]]
```

and I want to make a matrix where the left column is the elements of a and the right column is the elements of b

```py
c=[[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8]]
```

my intuition is that to do this the matricies need to be turned into vectors

---

EDIT:

I am not sure what types the matricies that I am concerned with are outside this toy example - and haven't been able to use the answers given to work with my matricies.

My matricies come from the code:

```
#axes 3d wants me to generate 2 matrixes to map onto a wire plot 
x_grid  = np.arange(100, 1000, 100)
y_grid  = np.arange(300, 30000, 100)
x_grid2 = np.matlib.repmat(x_grid,len(x_grid),1)
y_grid2 = np.matlib.repmat(y_grid,len(y_grid),1)
```

where x_grid2 and y_grid2 take the place of a and b in the toy example. My intuition is that they should be np arrays - but after getting an error and looking thorugh the documentation I am not sure

Comment: Your code uses `lists` but your question is about `numpy` matrices. It's unclear if you use `np.ndarray` or `np.matrix` (which are recommened not to use).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've eddited the question

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])

c = np.array([a.flatten(), b.flatten()]).T

print(c)
# [[1 5]
#  [2 6]
#  [3 7]
#  [4 8]]
```

Comment: with my arrays the c given by that process was the equivalent of array([array([  1,2,3,4]),
       array([1,2,3,4])]) I have no idea why

Comment: @Abijah From looking at your edited question, I believe it is because your `a` and `b` arrays are different size.  `x_grid2.shape = (9, 9)` while `y_grid2.shape=(297, 297)`.  I believe you may be using `np.arange` incorrectly; the last number specifies the step size, not the number elements.  Try `np.linspace` instead.  In addition, use `np.meshgrid` to convert the vectors into coordinate arrays instead of `np.matlib.repmat`.